# Swift 4 Load 3D Models from Firebase

Tags: firebase, swift4, firebase-storage, scenekit

I'm trying to get a 3D Model which is stored in Firebase into my iOS Application.

Right now I stored the default Object (ship.scn) into my Firebase Storage.

How can I convert the Data, which I get from Firebase, to a SCNNode?

This is my Code right now:

```
 let storage = Storage.storage().reference()
    let modelPath = storage.child("models/ship.scn")
    print("ModelPath: \(modelPath)")
    modelPath.getMetadata { (metaData, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("ERROR: ", error!)
        }else{
            print("Metadata: \(metaData!)")
        }
    }

    // this is what firebase shows for images
    // how can i get the Data as SCNNode?
    modelPath.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { (data, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("Error getData: \(error!)")
        }else {
            print(data)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem by downloading the 3D Object from firebase into the devices document folder.
So when I need the 3D-object I create a reference to the downloaded 3D-Object

write To Directory: (where modelPath is the storage.child('your path') in firebase)

```
   let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as String
   let tempDirectory = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: paths, isDirectory: true)
   let targetUrl = tempDirectory.appendingPathComponent("ship.scn")
   modelPath.write(toFile: targetUrl) { (url, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print("ERROR: \(error!)")
                }else{
                    print("modelPath.write OKAY")
                }
           }
```

load 3D file from directory:

```
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as String
    let tempDirectory = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: paths, isDirectory: true)
    let targetUrl = tempDirectory.appendingPathComponent("\ship.scn")
    var sceneForNode: SCNScene? = nil
    do {
        // load the 3D-Model node from directory path
        sceneForNode = try SCNScene(url: targetUrl, options: nil)
    }catch{
        print(error)
    }
    // create node to display on scene
    let node: SCNNode? = sceneForNode?.rootNode.childNode(withName: "ship", recursively: true)
```